# sql server 2012 DTSPackage Config File Exception

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a dtspackage which is executed through the C# coding.Earlier we have used sql server 2008 r2, Now we have moved to sql server 2012. The package was working fine with sql server 2008 while executing through C#code.But now while loading the Config file it throwing the exception like **

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsTaskException was caught
>   Message=Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005
>   (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))   Source=Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap
>   ErrorCode=-2147352571   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.ImportConfigurationFile(String
>   str)

**

```
 public bool ExecuteDtsService()
    {
        bool retval = false;
        StringBuilder strBldrErrorMsg = new StringBuilder();
        Package pkg;
        Application app= new Application();
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        ExecuteDTSEventListener eventListener = new ExecuteDTSEventListener();
        try
        {
            String pkgLocation = objProcess.SSISFilePath + pathSpecifier + objProcess.JobName;
            String pkLocationDtsConfig = objProcess.ConfigFilePath + pathSpecifier + objProcess.ConfigeFileName;
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
            pkg.ImportConfigurationFile(pkLocationDtsConfig); //getting error here

            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
            if (pkgResults.ToString().Equals("Success"))
            {
                retval = true;
            }
            else if (pkgResults.ToString().Equals("Failure"))
            {
                foreach (DtsError local_DtsError in pkg.Errors)
                {
                    strBldrErrorMsg.Append(local_DtsError.Description.ToString());
                }
                ReadLog(strBldrErrorMsg.ToString());
            }
            return retval;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            objUtility.WriteLogFile(ex, "ExecuteDTSservice");
            return retval;
        }

    }
```

The DTS package will download the xml content and transform to table.And it download one excel file and fetch the data from the excel.

The package running successful when i execute through the Execute Package Utility

Please guide me to fix the issue.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: while debugging what were values for pkgLocation and  pkLocationDtsConfig variables. Or just for troubleshooting try hard coded values.

Comment: I have debugged. pkgLocation and pkLocationDtsConfig are correct only.thanks for your reply.

Comment: As of now I resolve the Issue by assigning dummy values for empty Values in the Config file.Since In our package we will assign the values in Run time.